# Windows more command asks for user input

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with more command to skip the first few lines of the file and print the rest. I am using `more +6 file_name`. I see that it opens some percentage of the file and asks the user to enter the prompt so that it can load the next portion. I tried redirecting the output of the more command to a file using the `>` operation to another file and still have the same problem.

https://ss64.com/nt/more.html

```
When MORE is used without any redirection symbols it will display the percent complete e.g.

MORE /E myfile.txt
--More (17%) --
```

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Yes.  If the file is more than 64K lines, `MORE` will prompt you to continue.

Comment: So is there a way to circumvent this problem @Squashman. Or do I have to resort to reading the file using a for-loop and skipping the first 6 lines :(

Comment: You will need to use a `FOR /F` to read the file. Has been discussed here on SO and on DosTips.com.  Nobody has found a way around that afaik.

Comment: Even if you piped some prompt reply in (like `echo/| more +6 infile.txt > outfile.txt`) you'd get the prompt text in the output file; `for /F` however limits the lengths of each line to 8K characters, so depending on your data you might need to switch to another language like PowerShell...

Answer (score 0):

The [`more` command](http://ss64.com/nt/more.html) prompts for user input even when you redirect its output to a file, as soon as 64K lines have been encountered. In addition, `more` expands <kbd>TABs</kbd> to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.

A work-around is to use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to skip the first 6 lines:

```cmd
> "outfile.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq skip=6 delims=" %%L in ("infile.txt") do @(
        echo(%%L
    )
)
```

This however limits the line length to 8K characters/bytes. Furthermore, this skips empty lines.

To keep empty lines, you could do this:

```cmd
> "outfile.txt" (
    for /F "skip=6 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "infile.txt"') do @(
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

This precedes every line by a line number and a colon using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) intermittently, so no line appears empty to `for /F`; the prefix is removed when writing out the lines then. The line length is still limited though.

Comment: `for /F "skip=6 tokens=1,*delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "infile.txt"') do @echo(%%M`?

Comment: Just be aware that the method used in the comment above would remove any leading colons, **`:`** from your lines because `Delims` is greedy, _it counts multiple successive delimiters as one_.

Comment: That's why I prefer `find /n /v ""` over `findstr /n "^"` (colons are pretty common, but a line starting with `]` should be very very rare.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this simpler method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278628/778560):

```
< myfile.txt (

   rem Skip the first 6 lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,6) do set /P "="

   rem Show the rest
   findstr "^"

)
```

This method may fail if the skipped lines are longer than 1023 characters, that is the limit of `set /P` command.

Comment: Besides the worse line length limitation, this requires that the last line in the text file is terminated by a line-break, as otherwise, `findstr` may hang (depending on Windows version; on Windows 7 it hangs)...